# How and or When to Utilize Em-Dashes?

Tags: punctuation

In grammar, may you get to place em-dashes former to placing parenthesis?

> The tired, hungry — (and probably unfriendly) — lion roared.

And which sentence contains all right punctuation?

> The tired, hungry—and probably unfriendly—lion roared.
>
> The tired, hungry, (and probably unfriendly) lion roared.
>
> The tired, hungry, (and probably unfriendly), lion roared.
>
> The tired, hungry, and probably unfriendly lion roared.

Comment: Don't use commas with parens. So: _The tired, hungry (and probably unfriendly) lion roard_. As for which is "correct," there's not just one way to do this.

Comment: So it seems you may mostly get to utilize any. And you may not get to utilize *The tired, hungry, (and probably unfriendly) lion roared.* or *The tired, hungry, (and probably unfriendly), lion roared.*. I thank you, J.R.♦.

Comment: Well, yes, but using _both em-dashes and parentheses_ is overkill. Use one or the other, but not both. So for your first example & question the answer is no.

Comment: em-dashes are used to set the parenthetic remark off *in lieu of* parentheses and commas.  Note: the parenthetic clause or phrase, if removed, should yield a grammatical sentence that "stands on its own".

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for the first one. If it helps, try visualizing the sentence with the emphasized or parenthesized phrase deleted. In which case:

The tired, hungry lion roared. <-- Looks OK.

The tired, hungry, lion roared. <-- That comma after hungry is looking unnatural.

The tired, hungry, , lion roared. <-- Sequential commas. *Shudder*

The tired, hungry, and probably unfriendly lion roared. <-- This one looks good, and would also be my choice if I were to avoid em-dashes.